# How to send the values in paths in jquery?

Tags: jquery

I'm using the following code..

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
    $("#test a").click(function(){
      var labelTo = $(this).text();
      window.location = '#{root_path(labelTo)}';

    });
 });
```

I just want to send the value labelTo in root_path..but its giving following error

undefined local variable or method `labelTo' for #

any solution??

Comment: Is root_path a function which returns something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If root_path is a function which returns something then you can use like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
    $("#test a").click(function(){
      var labelTo = $(this).text();
      window.location = '#' + root_path(labelTo);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The obvious thought that comes to mind is

```
window.location = '#{root_path(' + labelTo + ')}';
```

but what are those braces for?